# I wrote a code with buffer in js to create an "html" file, but my code created a "jpg" file

Tags: discord, discord.js, buffer

I wrote a code with node.js that discord can create and send HTML page based on messages (such as discord-html-transcripts) with buffer. But in my code, there is no sign of "file.jpg" file, but it sends this file in Discord

---

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (interaction.customId === 'backup') {
        const messages = await fetchAll.messages(interaction.channel, {
            reverseArray: true
        });
 
        let messageHTML = '';
        messages.forEach((msg) => {
            let attachmentsHTML = '';
            msg.attachments.forEach((attachment) => {
                attachmentsHTML += `<a href="${attachment.url}" target="_blank">[ ${attachment.name} ]</a>`;
            });
            messageHTML += `
                <div>
                    <strong>${msg.author.username}</strong>
                    <span>${new Date(msg.createdTimestamp).toLocaleString()}</span>
                    <p>${msg.content}</p>
                    ${attachmentsHTML}
                </div>
            `;
        });
 
        const attachment = new AttachmentBuilder(Buffer.from(`
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <title>Backup For #${interaction.channel.name}</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h1>Backup For #${interaction.channel.name}</h1>
                    ${messageHTML}
                </body>
            </html>
        `, 'utf-8'), `backup-${interaction.channel.name}.html`);
 
        const backupEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle(`Backup For #${interaction.channel.name}`)
            .setColor('#00ff00');
 
        await interaction.reply({
            content: null,
            embeds: [backupEmbed],
            files: [attachment]
        });
    }
});
```